# Untranslatable Character When Using oREPLACE in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, regexp-replace

I'm trying to replace double spaces in a text field with just one space. I'm using Teradata but I am not sure which version. I use Toad Data Point to query the data.

I've used a few different methods to get this done including REGEXP_REPLACE, OREPLACE, AND TRANSLATE but I keep getting an error thrown: [Teradata Database] [6706] The string contains an untranslatable character.

So, I thought to use TRANSLATE_CHK in a CASE statement but I get the same error.

Here is my latest attempt.

```
select
  TSB.SESSION_CREW_MBRS,
  TRANSLATE_CHK(TSB.SESSION_CREW_MBRS USING LATIN_TO_UNICODE) as TransChk,
  CASE
    WHEN TRANSLATE_CHK(TSB.SESSION_CREW_MBRS USING LATIN_TO_UNICODE) = 0
      THEN OREPLACE(TSB.SESSION_CREW_MBRS, '  ', ' ') 
    ELSE TSB.SESSION_CREW_MBRS
  END AS RepChk
FROM 
  myDatabase TSB
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The problem with the CASE is that there is an implicit translation being done for the ELSE because both THEN and ELSE conditions have to return the same data type (VARCHAR CHARACTER SET UNICODE in this case). You could change the THEN part to return CHARACTER SET LATIN by translating the literals or using CHR function, or you could explicitly TRANSLATE(... WITH ERROR) in the ELSE part. Or you could replace the offending CHR(26) with something else first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this to translate the "error substitution character" to a different LATIN character (in this example, to ¿ *inverted question mark*) before removing the excess spaces:

```
select
  TSB.SESSION_CREW_MBRS,
  TRANSLATE_CHK(TSB.SESSION_CREW_MBRS USING LATIN_TO_UNICODE) as TransChk,
  OREPLACE(OTRANSLATE(TSB.SESSION_CREW_MBRS,CHR(26),CHR(191)),'  ', ' ') AS RepChk
FROM 
  myDatabase TSB
```

Comment: This worked for me in the end but was pretty taxing on my spool space so I had to do some filtering before I applied it. Appreciate your help and thank you.

Comment: Yes, especially if you are grouping/sorting the result you may want to CAST the output of certain functions like OREPLACE or REGEXP_REPLACE to the "proper" size because the function result type is a rather large VARCHAR.